# How do I make a category name on x-axis clickable in a polar graph?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Tried 'useHTML`and directly set`yyy` but failed.

Tried to manually adjust the HTML by using jQuery code like

`$('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels').find('text:eq(0)').html('<a href="#go">ttt</a>')`

failed too. But if I enter that code from Chrome timeline, it works.

Is it possible to make the text clickable? (a link or a button, both are fine, just need to listen to its click event)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use xAxis.labels.formatter in your case. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/55vk72pp/

Comment: Cool. I'm just wondering, is `useHTML` not recommended to use now?

Comment: You may use useHTML, it should not be any problem with Highcharts, but I think that your html also should be inside your formatter.

Comment: Oh, maybe it is because I did not use formatter... Is there any docs about `formatter` ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, here you can find information about it: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: I just noticed that it has turned the `a` tag into a `onclick` style on a `tspan`, like: `<tspan onclick="location.href=&quot;http://www.bing.com/serach?q=foobar&quot;" style="cursor: pointer;">Foobar</tspan>`, in this way, the `target="_blank"` won't be applied. What should I do if I want that? Thanks!

Comment: btw, in this case, I can't even trigger a function when clicking on that label.

Comment: For click events on labels I think that better is to use custom-events plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events